# можно ли как-то узнать cколько миллисекунд мы были в определенном состоянии redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

можно ли как-то узнать cколько миллисекунд мы были в определенном состоянии redux или только таймер свой делать?

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

воспользуйтесь redux devtools расширением для браузера, в нем есть время между шагами.

Comment: мне нужно именно записывать к себе это время. а не просто смотреть

Comment: можно ли его как-то достать отуда?

Comment: Нужно найти сколько времени юзер находится в определенном состоянии redux

Answer (score 0):

Можно, для этого необходимо написать middleware, в котором будет логироваться время через console.time (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(timeLogging)
);

const logger = store => next => action => {
    console.log('dispatching', action);
    console.time(action);
    let result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    console.timeEnd(action);
    return result
}
```

более подробная информация по middleware тут - https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware

Comment: вы можете вместо логирования в консоль пробрасывать в мидлваре диспатчить дополнительные экшены, например: `store.dispatch('LOG_TIME', { time, action })`. можно сделать проверку на перехват только определенных экшенов, за которыми вам важно следить и отправлять статистику